# Copy CSS classes from one element to another, but exclude specific class

Tags: jquery, css

I am using the following script to copy classes from one element to another:

```
jQuery("#copyto").attr("class", jQuery("#copyfrom").attr("class"));
```

`#copyfrom` looks like this:

```
<div class="blah active">
```

I'd like to exclude the 'blah' class and only copy 'active'.

Is that possible some how?

Comment: Is it specifically one class (`blah`) that you want to remove, or multiple classes (a blacklist), or do you only want to preserve a single class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Option 1 (old school):**

```
var copyfrom = document.getElementById('copyfrom'),
    copyto   = document.getElementById('copyto');
var old = " "+copyfrom.className+" ";
copyto.className = old.replace(' blah ','');

// alternatively
copyto.className = copyfrom.className.replace(/(^|\s)blah(\s|$)/,'');
```

**Option 2 (new school):**

```
copyto.className = copyfrom.className;
copyto.classList.remove( 'blah' );
```

**Option 3 (just jQuery):**

```
$('#copyto').attr('class',$('#copyfrom').attr('class')).removeClass('blah');
```

Comment: @dippas You're partially correct; I had a typo in the first one. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yrtru74a/) shows all 3 working.

Comment: my bad I did something wrong in my tests on 3rd option.